# What is the origin of multiple 'plotlines' tabular diagram?

Tags: creative-writing, plot, narrative, subplot

Where did the concept of multiple parallel plotlines (that may or may not interact and converge) originate? These days they're also known as throughlines, subplots, narrative/character arcs, series.

I know it is quite an intuitive thing, but I would really like to know the first recorded instance of someone talking about it/teaching the tabular method (each row/column is an arc and each column/row is a point in time-> usually divided into Acts or chapters). In fact, I can't find any book at all that discusses this tabular method.

Comment: Here is an example http://imgur.com/joT1NeL

Answer (score 1):

A Wikipedia article for [through line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Through_line) explaines that Konstantin Stanislavsky suggested the concept in his method of training actors, the "[Stanislavski system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanislavski%27s_system)", at the beginning of the 20th century.

Using Google book search brings up about [234.000 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22throughline%22%20OR%20%22through%20line%22&ie=utf-8&tbm=bks).

If you search for "[through line stanislavski](https://www.google.com/search?q=through%20line%20stanislavski)" – everyone except Wikipedia seems to write his name with an "i" at the end –, you will find a plethora of articles that explain Stanislavski's concept in detail and give references to his writings.

The concept of throughlines is one foundation for the theory behind the story writing software [Dramatica Story Expert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Through_line). Here is a diagram visualizing throughlines as conceptualized by the authors of Dramatica:

[image]

Comment: But does this answer the question?